# Codeigniter 2.1, Jquery - delete all checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment, I am confused by this problem. How can I delete all files that have been checked?
This is the function to select or unselect checkboxes:

```
var del_selected = $('.zute_strane_izmena_obrisi_sve'),
del_url = del_selected.attr('href'),
selektuj_sve = $('.zute_strane_izmena_selektuj_sve'),
slike = $('.zuta_strana_trenutne_slike'),
box = slike.find(':checkbox'),
selektovane_slike = [];

    selektuj_sve.on('click', function(){
        $(this).text(box.is(':checked') ? 'Selektuj Sve Slike' : 'Deselektuj Sve Slike');
        box.attr('checked', !box.is(':checked'));
    });
```

Jquery for now (it is working without error):

```
del_selected.on('click', function(e){

    box.filter(':checked').each(function(){
        selektovane_slike.push($(this).val());
        $(this).parent().slideUp('fast');
    });
    data = JSON.stringify(box.serializeArray(), null, 2);

    console.log(data);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Where to go from here?

Comment: You need to POST the array you're building (selektovane_slike) to your controller, which will then loop through it and delete the items via PHP.

Comment: That is an idea, but I don't now how to work with json and PHP, and I am exploring this area at the moment.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you asking about deleting files on the server or the client?

Comment: Deleting the files is happening on the server.

Comment: So are you struggling with getting the data to the PHP, parsing the data in PHP, or actually deleting the files?  Have you tried anything in PHP yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to the server to delete the files. You need to be very careful about file permissions. The web server either needs to have permission to delete, or it needs to defer the action to a process that does (such as by writing the request to the database or a queue).

Comment: Ajax part is not the problem. The problem is within PHP and JSON. I am not familiar with this area.